# How to access to current element in remote validation using jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validate to validate forms.
I need to access to the current validated element in remote validation, in particular I need to get current element (input) name, without using ID.

This is my piece of code:

```
remote: {
    url: '/myurl.php',
    data: {
        inputName: function() {
            // HERE I NEED TO ACCESS TO THE CURRENT INPUT NAME ATTRIBUTE ("email") WITHOUT USING AN ID
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method

Comment: I know the documentation.... But I can't solve my problem

Comment: You never explained the problem... like why would you need the `name` attribute in this location?  The data from this element is already sent by default.  In other words, you don't even need the `data` option at all when using `remote` unless you're sending ***additional*** data.  Again, refer to the examples in the documentation.

Comment: I need the "name" attribute in the request because I'm using a unique php function to remotly validate my forms. In this php function I need to know the name of the element to validate (example: $_REQUEST["email"]) that changes for any remote validation...

Comment: The name is already sent by default with the Ajax request.   Access in PHP with `$_GET["name"]`.

Answer (score 0):

> I need the "name" attribute in the request...

By default, the `name` is already part of the request.  [As per the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/), the default method is `GET`, so within your PHP, you can access the element with `$_GET["name"]`.  **You would not need to use the `data` option unless you need to send *other additional* data along with the value of this field.**

```
rules: {
    myInputName: {
        remote: '/myurl.php'
    }
}
```

Then within `myurl.php`...

```
$_GET['myInputName'] // <- value of the field sent via the 'remote' request
```